# Passing data to fields in a Razor view using MVC Core form tag helper

Tags: .net, ajax, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have a form created with the MVC Core tag helper for forms. In this form I have a select list. Currently when an item in the list is clicked, that item is sent to the action method in the controller. 
Instead of this default behavior, is it possible to explicitly select the data that is being passed to the field behind the select list?

In the code below, as each item in the select list is clicked, using a script it builds up a table by appending items. I want to be able to pass the data in this table as a list to the field behind the select list(SubjectAreasOfProgramme)

(The foreach loop is just to build up the table when the page loads with existing items)

```
<form asp-action="SaveProgrammeData" asp-controller="ProgrammeMarketing" 
    method="post" asp-antiforgery="true" id="SaveSubjectAreas" data- 
    ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST"
    data-ajax-success="UpdateFields" data-ajax-failure="UpdateFields" 
    data-ajax-update="overview">

<select asp-for="SubjectAreasOfProgramme"
    asp-items="Model.SubjectAreasForDropdown.ForEach(a => a.Selected = 
    Model.SubjectAreasOfProgramme.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(a.Value))"> 
</select>

<table id="overview" class="table table-sm table-borderless">
    @foreach (var item in Model.SubjectAreasOfProgramme){
        <tr><td>@item</td></tr>
    }
</table>

//Function to append each item clicked in dropdown box to table
    $("#subjectlist")
        .change(function () {
            $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                $('#overview').append("<tr id='this.value'><td>" + 
                $(this).text() + "</td><td id=" + this.value + ">" + "X" + 
                "</td></tr>");
            });
        })
        .trigger("change");
```